# How can I change the definition of "line" in grep?

Tags: grep

`grep` will return the lines in a file that match a certain pattern:

`grep pattern file`

Will search through *file* and return all the lines matching *pattern*.

My code base has many multi-line statements, such as:

```
int x = somefunc(a,
                 b,
                 10, 
                 someclass(10),
                 foo,
                 bar);
```

I want to be able to `grep` my file and return the entire statement, not only the line.  For instance, if I want all the calls to `somefunc` that use the `foo`, I could do:

```
grep -e 'somefunc.*foo' filename
```

and get the entire function call, which I can pipe in to another program for further processing:

```
    grep -e 'somefunc.*foo' filename | grep -v bar
```

Essentially, I want to tell `grep` that my lines end with `;` and not with `EOL`.

I can't use the `-C`, `-A` or `-B` switches, since I don't always know how many lines will be in the statement.  For instance, the example above could be written as:

```
int x = somefunc(a, b,
                 10, someclass(10),
                 foo, bar);
```

Is there any way to do this with `grep` or any other common tool?

Comment: Hi Nathan , would you please accept any of the following answer which best suited your requirement?

Comment: I tried them, but none of them was really satisfactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have a file `test_grep` with contents:

```
int x = somefunc(a,
                 b,
                 10,
                 someclass(10),
                 foo,
                 bar);

float y = 2

int z  = somefunc(a, b,
                 10, someclass(10),
                 foo, bar);

float w = 4
```

---

```
grep -Pzo  '(?s)somefunc\(.*?foo.*?\);' test_grep
```

`P` - allows Perl regular expresssions

`z` - suppress newline at the end of line, subtituting it for null character.

`o` - outputs only matched parts

`(?s)` - `PCRE_DOTALL` mode, treats `.` as any character or newline

---

The output(for the above example):

```
somefunc(a,
                 b,
                 10, 
                 someclass(10),
                 foo,
                 bar);
somefunc(a, b,
                 10, someclass(10),
                 foo, bar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course a *perl* one-liner fits the bill here.

```
perl -00 -nE 'say $& while /somefunc.*?foo/sg' file
```

- `-00` Pragraph mode. *Perl* reads the file in chunks separated by blank lines.
- `-n` Loop over every read paragraph
- `-E` Script follows on the commandline
- `/s` This regex modifier extends the definition of the pattern `.` to include `\n`
- `while /`*regex*`/g` The `while` and `/g` combination looks for another match in the paragraph after the first is found. You may prefer `if` if you only want the first match
  a newline
- `*?` is a regex quantifier that means *as few as possible*. Leave off the `?` and the unadorned `*` means *as many as possible*. Not really what you want here.
- `$&` expands to whatever the last matching regex matched

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to change the definitions of RECORD/LINE. `RS` is default set to new line, you can change it as per requirement. In following Example, `RS` is changed to `;`. Following line will search for `someclass2` string in the "*code records which ends with `;`"*

`awk` command:

```
awk -v RS=';' '/someclass2/' input
```

Example:

```
awk -v RS=';' '/someclass2/' input
int x = somefunc(a,
                 b,
                 10,
                 someclass2(10),
                 foo,
                 bar)
```

Following was the input text used :

```
cat input
int x = somefunc(a,
                 b,
                 10,
                 someclass0(10),
                 foo,
                 bar);

int x = somefunc(a,
                 b,
                 10,
                 someclass1(10),
                 foo,
                 bar);

int x = somefunc(a,
                 b,
                 10,
                 someclass2(10),
                 foo,
                 bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, do just what you said. Change `;` to `\n` and `\n` to `;`, do the grep, and change them back again.

```
re=$1
cat "$@" | # tr only reads from stdin
    tr '\n;' ';\n' |
    grep -- "$re" |
    tr '\n;' ';\n'
```